# Gradle Handshake Failure

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After installing android studio and when attempting to open an existing Android project. When android studio attempts to do a gradle sync the following error is displayed.

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:emulatorRuntimeClasspath'.
    Could not determine artifacts for net.danlew:android.joda:2.7.2
    Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/danlew/android.joda/2.7.2/android.joda-2.7.2.aar'.
    Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/danlew/android.joda/2.7.2/android.joda-2.7.2.aar'.
    Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

The export log looks as follows:

```
2018-11-22 13:40:48,883 [d thread 4]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Received fatal alert: handshake_failure 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:466)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:943)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:923)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:209)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:140)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:550)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:647)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After running the following curl command (curl --verbose -X HEAD https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/danlew/android.joda/2.7.2/android.joda-2.7.2.aar)as suggested by @Benoit. I get the following:
[image: Curl Command Result]

Comment: Might be a temporary problem on bintray server.

Comment: @Benoit It has been giving us an issue since yesterday

Comment: Can you please indicate the different versions of the tools: Java, Gradle and Android?

Comment: @LouisJacomet java 1.8, Gradel 3.2.1, Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: If you have `curl` command on your machine, you can try `curl --verbose -X HEAD https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/danlew/android.joda/2.7.2/android.joda-2.7.2.aar`. This way you will check if the problem is on your whole system or just in Android Studio/Gradle.

Comment: Still no change after trying again today. When the project is loaded cannot even find the SDK

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Firefox indicates a SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP error.  Looks like someone at bintray configured cloudfront incorrectly.

Comment: @MichaelWeinand, I resolved the issue by changing the windows defender settings.

Comment: @George, which Windows Defender settings?  I do get a "Connection Blocked" message from Windows 10 occasionally but I could not find anything online that even referred to that message.